# How can you access the Chromium cookies on the command line?

Tags: chrome, cookie

I would like to get access to the Chromium cookies on the command line -- externally to chrome and without the use of any extensions. Where does Chromium store the cookies on disk? Is this possible and how would I go about doing it?

I have an external utility that wants to authenticate with a cookie of a session that has already passed authentication. I do not want to have to keep opening up the Chromium Dev tools and finding it to copy-and-paste.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie database is stored in,

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Cookies
```

Where "Default" will change if you actually create profiles in Chromium. You will want `name` and `encrypted_value` from the `cookies` table.

```sql
SELECT name,encrypted_value
FROM cookies
WHERE host_key = "mysite.com";
```

From the command line that looks like this

```bash
cat <<EOT | sqlite3 "$HOME/.config/chromium/Default/Cookies" -json
    SELECT name,encrypted_value
    FROM cookies
    WHERE host_key = "foobar.com";
EOT
```

Decrypting the `encrypted_value` is a bit complex. I'll answer how to do that this week.